# ReporteRs FlexTable taking ages on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: reporters

The University I work for has just switched to Windows Server 2012 R2 and I am finding that the FlexTable command on ReporteRs takes extremely long to run; where previously it would have taken less than a minute, it is now taking over 15 minutes.

Is there a known issue anyone is aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wait until the end of the operation, package gdtools is scanning your system fonts as it didn't find any available list when starting. It should only happen once

Comment: Thanks David. It actually happened several times when I reported it the other day, but I have now tested it again and it's much faster.